# C++ compile-time continuations inlining

Tags: c++

I'm trying to inline the following C++ code:

```
    __attribute__((always_inline)) static void inline compose(const char* s, std::function<void(const char *)> f) {
       std::cout << s << std::endl;
       f(s);
   }

   // --------------- Main ---------------
   int main() {
       // Nest three things
       compose("hello world", [](const char *s) {
           compose("hello again", [](const char *s) {
               compose("hello third time", [](const char *s) {
                   return;
               });
           });
       });

       return 0;
   }
```

Here my continuations are of type `std::function<void(const char*)>` and what I wanted from compiler with the `always_inline` option was to transform it to a single call-site that looks like this:

```
// --------------- Main ---------------
   int main() {
       // Nest three things
       std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "hello again" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "hello third time" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
```

Is it possible to do this in compile-time? I think the compiler cannot do this automatically but I was thinking the preprocessor might, with constexpr and C++17.

Comment: Marking compose as constexpr, which would be the obvious solution does not work, I tried adding constexpr to the lambdas, but to no avail.

Comment: How do you know the compiler cannot automatically optimize your continuation code to equivalent performance to the second version? Have you tried godbolt?

Comment: I use llvm and I just observed the IR. I’m not familiar with godbolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang optimizes it pretty well. The use of `std::function<>` only creates a small overhead associated with type erasure:

Continuation style: https://godbolt.org/g/FxHSnV

Direct style: https://godbolt.org/g/N1b8QC

I have used a `dummy_write()` to avoid the complicated-looking assembly generated with `iostream` and `std::cout`.

This type erasure can be eliminated by templating `compose` instead of using `std::function`: https://godbolt.org/g/7QceN6

```
template<typename Func>
__attribute__((always_inline))
static void inline compose(const char* s, Func f) {
    dummy_write(s);
    f(s);
}
```

Comment: That’s a great use of templates, thanks! Just curious, why are there four calls to dummy_write in the continuation style assembly?

Comment: The fourth `dummy_write` appears to be part of an `_M_invoke()` method associated with the `std::function` implementation. It's not actually called in `main()`, but it wasn't optimized out. An unoptimized use of `std::function` would likely call the `_M_invoke()`.

Comment: Thank ls for the further explanation!